# magento mage bridge extension disable is breaking the site

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions

I have one magento site. Today I just looged in to the admin dashboard and went through the `system-> configuration-> Advanced-> advanced -> Disable Modules Output -> Yireo_MageBridge-> and made disable from enable`. After that the total site became blank`(Magento admin page and home page  completely blank, no errors to be found anywhere)` . It did not showed anything. Even after going through some blogs and suggestion I edit my`magento index.php` to check some issue I made like this

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

But after all the debug I did not find anything. When I logged into my site `magentroot/index.php/admin` but still it is showing completely blank page. So can you tell me how to solve this issue? Any help and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: check for maintenance.flag file in the root.delete it if present. i had the same problem with one extension

Comment: can you tell me the exact file path for this?

Comment: If set, the maintenance.flag file will be in the **Magento root folder**. This is the base folder where Magento was installed. Either in your http server document root or the Magento subfolder off of that. Also, we're dealing with issues being caused by a **third party module**. You will get better help dealing with these by contacting the developer, in this case **Yireo**. Often with these modules, there isn't a large enough installed base for us to have experienced each way they can fail. The developer on the other hand has had enough of an earful to know more quickly where to start.

Comment: Note that this does not disable the module - it disables the module *output* - specifically the content returned from instantiated blocks.

Comment: @NewUser:If your issue is solved please let the community know here

Comment: Disabling the XML-flag in app/etc/modules/Yireo_MageBridge.xml should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the module creator](https://twitter.com/yireo/status/367328181390692352) you should be able to solve the problem by disabling the module completely.

Just rename `app/etc/modules/Yireo_MageBridge.xml` to have an filename extension that's not `.xml`, or change the `active` flag inside the file from `true` to `false`.

As to the ultimate why — many modules are built such that they don't fully support the "Disable Module Output" feature.  This feature will skip loading a module's layout file — my guess would be there's PHP code in an Observer that assume a block's present, but because you've disable output it's not.